# Separar e imprimir direccion y número

Tags: python, lista, string, formato

estoy con una complicación al querer obtener el nombre completo de la calle de la dirección ingresada por el usuario. Al momento de obtener lo requerido solo me muestra el último elemento de la calle.

```
def format_address(address_string):
  house_number = 0
  street_name = []
  address = address_string.split(' ')
  print(address)

  for item in address:
    if item.isnumeric():
      house_number = item
      #print(house_number)
    else:
        street_name = item 
        print(street_name)
   
  # Return the formatted string  
  return "Street name: {} house number: {}".format(street_name, house_number)
print(format_address("Andrés Bello 450"))
print(format_address("North Center Drive 550"))

El resultado que muestra el código:

Street name: Bello house number: 450
Street name: Drive house number: 550

Y el resultado esperado que busco:
Street name: Andrés Bello house number: 450
Street name: North Center Drive house number: 550
```

Estaré atento a nuevos comentarios, muchas gracias.
Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Lo que está sucediendo es que en el `return` estas devolviendo `street_name` y `house_number` pero `street_name` únicamente contiene el último `string` de tu lista `address` ya que lo asignas en el ciclo `for`

En lugar de asignar el valor directamente a `street_name` en esta línea (Que por cierto, lo declaraste como lista y luego en esta línea eliminas la lista)

```
street_name = item
```

Puedes agregar `item` a la lista utilizando el método `append()`

```
street_name.append(item)
```

Y al hacer `return` puedes utilizar el método `join()` para juntar cada uno de los elementos de tu lista en un único `string`

```
return "Street name: {} house number: {}".format(' '.join(street_name), house_number)
```

Ejemplo completo con los comentarios anteriores:

```
def format_address(address_string):
    house_number = 0
    street_name = []
    address = address_string.split(' ')

    for item in address:
        if item.isnumeric():
            house_number = item
        else:
            street_name.append(item)
   
    # Return the formatted string  
    return "Street name: {} house number: {}".format(' '.join(street_name), house_number)

print(format_address("Andrés Bello 450"))
print(format_address("North Center Drive 550"))
```

Esto devuelve:

```
Street name: Andrés Bello house number: 450
Street name: North Center Drive house number: 550
```